# Windows 10 Policy-based QoS application specific not working

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, group-policy

I have created a Policy-based QoS for an application called 3CXWin8Phone.exe to set DSCP to 48 and it does not seem to be working. I am using Wireshark to watch the packets.  The computer is using Azure AD, we do have our old on premise windows domain controller still running which is handling DHCP.

I have tried...

- cmd.exe which didn't work
- All Applications which worked
- outlook.exe which worked
- Setting via PowerShell which didn't work
- Reboots after changing
- Using the full path
- Set Registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\QoS\Do not use NLA` = 1

As an added issue after removing the "All Applications" policy it is still setting packets with the DSCP that I had set, I have rebooted.

I thought a reboot was meant to fix everything.  The goal is to use QoS with the 3CX Windows Client.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Edit: Turns out cmd.exe not a great test, outlook.exe works fine

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Giday, the computer is using Azure AD, we do have our old on premise windows domain controller still running that is handling DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was user error, I hadn't setup the software with a user and it looks like it was not chatting over the network as I was expecting.

It is now working as expected.  I used the full path and program name, rebooted the computer and am now seeing the expected DSCP tags in wireshark.

Comment: If this worked, you can also accept your own answer to let other people searching that this worked for you. Regards!